# Split single record into Multiple records in Unix shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line

I have record

Example:

```
EMP_ID|EMP_NAME|AGE|SALARAy
123456|XXXXXXXXX|30|10000000
```

Is there a way i can split the record into multiple records. Example output should be like

```
EMP_ID|Attributes
123456|XXXXXXX
123456|30
123456|10000000
```

I want to split the same record into multiple records. Here Employee id is my unique column and remaining 3 columns i want to run in a loop and create 3 records. Like EMP_ID|EMP_NAME , EMP_ID|AGE , EMP_ID|SALARY.  I may have some more columns as well but for sample i have provided 3 columns along with Employee id.

Please help me with any suggestion.

Comment: I do not know if you want `awk` , but this should work `awk  -F'|' -vOFS='|'  'NR==1{print}NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$i}'  record_file`

Comment: @PS thanks a lot for the reply. I am okay with anu approach . Let me try Awk as per you suggestion. Please let me know if any other approaches as well available.

Comment: @PS In this output i have made EMP_ID as a uniue column. But if i make EMP_ID & EMP_NAME as unique column and other 2 columns i want to run in loop and create 2 records -- What will be the change i need to update in the command ?\

Comment: @PS -- Can i get header also for this approach ?

Comment: you should add what is your expected output for better clarity.

Comment: @PS i have updated the expected output..

Comment: you can do `awk 'BEGIN{print "EMP_ID|Attributes"}...............rest awk command......'`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Record of lines with fields separated by a special delimiter character such as `|` can be manipulated by basic Unix command line tools such as `awk`. For example with your input records in file `records.txt`:

```
awk -F\| 'NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1"|"$(i)}}' records.txt
```

I recommend to read a awk tutorial and play around with it. Related command line tools worth to learn include `grep`, `sort`, `wc`, `uniq`, `head`, `tail`, and `cut`.  If you regularly do data processing of delimiter-separated files, you will likely need them on a daily basis. As soon as your data structuring format gets more complex (e.g. CSV format with possibility to also use the delimiter character in field values) you need more specific tools, for instance see [this question on CSV tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/is-there-a-robust-command-line-tool-for-processing-csv-files/7434) or [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) for processing JSON. Still knowledge of basic Unix command line tools will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks Jakob . Let me try and reply again in few minutes.

Comment: Then start the loop with column `3` and print both `$1 and `$2`. This is not the right place to walk you through your whole use case but you should get the general direction which tools to use for which tasks.

Comment: @avinash sorry I don't understand. Two general remarks about Stackoverflow: Please don't post the same comment twice. If you like an answer, upvote it (you seem to have downvoted instead?)

Comment: @ Jakob. I have marked it as Answer already before 10mins and i even dont know how to downvote. I just clicked on "tick" mark and marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
record='123456|XXXXXXXXX|30|10000000'
IFS='|' read -ra fields <<<"$record"
for ((i=1; i < "${#fields[@]}"; i++)); do 
    printf "%s|%s\n" "${fields[0]}" "${fields[i]}"
done
```

```
123456|XXXXXXXXX
123456|30
123456|10000000
```

For the whole file:

```
{
    IFS= read -r header
    while IFS='|' read -ra fields; do
        for ((i=1; i < "${#fields[@]}"; i++)); do 
            printf "%s|%s\n" "${fields[0]}" "${fields[i]}"
        done
    done
} < filename
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn. Is there any way i can get header as well. I just updated the expected output in the above description...

Comment: before the `while` loop, just `echo "EMP_ID|Attributes"`